# Need help finding the standard deviation?

Tags: probability

Consider a normal distribution curve where the middle 5 % of the area under the curve lies above the interval ( 6 , 12 ). Find the mean and standard deviation.

Consider a normal distribution curve where 85-th percentile is at 12 and the 25-th percentile is at 6. Find the mean and standard deviation.

Here is the work I have done so far:

[image]

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong in looking for the standard deviations? Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The middle $5\%$ is between $z=\pm0.06270678$.  I.e. $\Phi(-0.06270678)=0.475$ and $1-\Phi(0.6270678)=0.475$ so $2(0.475)=0.95$ is outside those bounds, and $0.05$ is inside.

So:
\begin{align}
\mu+0.06270678\sigma & = 12, \\
\mu-0.06270678\sigma & = 6.
\end{align}
Subtracting the second of these from the first gives $2(0.06270678\sigma)$ on the left and $12-6$ on the right.  Having found $\sigma$, you can plug that into either of the two equations above and find $\mu$.

Comment: I keep getting 4.784 as my standard deviation but this is also incorrect

Comment: It seems I misplaced a decimal point in a couple of these.  It is of course $0.06270678$ and NOT $0.6270678$.  It you have $2(0.06270678\sigma)=6$, you get $\sigma=6/(2\times0.06270678)=47.84172$.  The number you report, $4.784$, is merely that number with the decimal point moved over one place.  Since only $5\%$ of the probability is in that interval of length $6$, you have to expect the standard deviation to be much bigger than $4.784$, since after all, about $68\%$ should be between $\mu\pm\sigma$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I've fixed the typos.  Now all of them say $0.06270678$, not $0.6270678$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Ok, I see! Thank you